# How to add watermark on PDF file in pure JAVA?

Tags: java, pdf, watermark

I would like to know if it's possible to watermark PDF file without any library.

I managed to do that with *iText*, but I would like to do watermarks in pure JAVA.
If someone knows if and how it's possible, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory? Yes, it is. Most Java libraries that can produce watermarks are probably written in pure Java, so you could write that functionality yourself.

Practically? There aren't (to my knowledge; please correct me if I'm wrong) any core libraries that would allow you to manipulate PDFs in such a way, so you could either put a lot of work into basically copying part of iTexts functionality or just use a library.

Comment: Ok thanks.

So I'll check source code of itext to see how it works.
I'll give you my impressions when i found.

Thx for your reactivity.

Comment: You're welcome. Though honestly I don't see why you wouldn't want to use a library; why reinvent the wheel if it already exists?

Comment: For 2 reasons : first i want to know how it works for my personal knowledge. Second, it's about commercial licence.
I want to use this in a commercial software, publishing source code of this soft is impossible. So, I wanted to know to avoid the commercial licence of itext for my client.

But after having look at the code of iText, i think that the price for produce this function will be very higher that the commercial licence.

So thank you for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Watermarking to PDF can be added using the Java Library [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("HelloWorld.pdf");
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
    new FileOutputStream("NewHelloWorld.pdf"));
Image image = Image.getInstance("MyWatermark.png");

for (int i=1; i<= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
    PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);
    image.setAbsolutePosition(150f, 750f);
    content.addImage(image);
}

pdfStamper.close();
```

---

Here is another related example:
https://web.archive.org/web/20151023054638/http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/Watermarking

Comment: Example : http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/events/Watermarking

Comment: Thanks for your response but I know it is possible with iText, and as I said I already produce some code with iText.